# Adding a column to AspNetUserTokens using code first in Asp.Net core identity

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-5, asp.net-core-identity

I need to add a column to track encryption version of the 2FA key and recovery code stored in AspNetUserTokens table for an existing .Net5 web api application. I could directly use Sql command to do the migration. I'd like to use code first approach if possible. This doesn't seem to fall under existing patterns of AspNetUsers & AspNetRoles defined in the documentation. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

EF Core Code first approach allows you to add custom columns to IdentityToUserTokens. A few code changes will do it for you.

Create a new class inheriting from `IdentityUserToken<TKey>`

```cs
    public class ApplicationUserToken : IdentityUserToken<string>
    {
        public int CustomColumn { get; set; }
    }
```

Change your DbContext to the following

```cs
 public class ApplicationContext : IdentityDbContext<
        IdentityUser, IdentityRole, string,
        IdentityUserClaim<string>,
        IdentityUserRole<string>,
        IdentityUserLogin<string>,
        IdentityRoleClaim<string>,
        ApplicationUserToken> //Class inherited by IdentityUserToken<TKey>
    {
        public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }
    }
```

Migration after the changes

```cs
    public partial class Withcustomtokens : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
                name: "CustomColumn",
                table: "AspNetUserTokens",
                type: "int",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: 0);
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "CustomColumn",
                table: "AspNetUserTokens");
        }
    }
```

For indepth details about .net core identity customization, refer: [Identity model customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0)